# switch case in do while loop in dart

Tags: dart, switch-statement, do-while

**Question**:
Write a program to create grocery program in which we have first empty basket. Further whatever items users wants to buy he/she put into that basket. Use appropriate control Sturature and collection datatype.
**error** in case 6 when I press 6 program don't stop keep asking about enter your choice. I need help to fix this. I have to do when I press 6 program should be closed.

```
**Input:**
import 'dart:io';

void main(){

  List basket=[];
  int i;
  String str;
  stdout.write("How many items:");
  int n=int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    stdout.write("Item $i :");
    str=stdin.readLineSync()!;
    basket.add(str);
  }
  
  print("Choose Operation:");

  print("press 1: for insert new item");
  print("press 2: for delete an item");
  print("press 3: for update an item");
  print("press 4: for view basket");
  print("press 5: for clear basket");
  print("press 6: for exit");

  int ch=0;
    do {
      stdout.write("enter your choose:");
      int ch=int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

      switch(ch){
       case 1:
        stdout.write("enter item name:");
        str=stdin.readLineSync()!;
        basket.add(str);
        print("your list after insert item: $basket");
        break;

      case 2:
        stdout.write("Enter item name which you when to delete:");
        str=stdin.readLineSync()!;
        basket.remove(str);
        print("your list after deleted item: $basket");
        break;

      case 3:
        stdout.write("Enter item name which you when to remove:");
        str=stdin.readLineSync()!;
        basket.remove(str);
        stdout.write("Enter item name which you when to add:");
        str=stdin.readLineSync()!;
        basket.add(str);
        print("your list after updated item: $basket");
        break;

      case 4:
        print(basket);
        break;
      case 5:
        basket.clear();
        print(basket);
        break;
      case 6:
        break;
      default:
        print("unexpected operation enter the right operation");
        break;
      }
    } while (ch!=6);
       
}
```

**Output:**

```
 How many items:2
Item 1 :milk
Item 2 :apple
Choose Operation:
press 1: for insert new item
press 2: for delete an item
press 3: for update an item
press 4: for view basket
press 5: for clear basket
press 6: for exit
enter your choose:6
enter your choose:6
enter your choose:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have declared `ch` in two scopes (inside and outside of the loop). So when you modify `ch` inside the loop, you are actually modifying the `ch` variable defined at this line:

```
int ch = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
```

And not:

```
int ch = 0;
```

What you need to do is just remove the `int` part of your line inside the loop:

```
ch = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
```

Since we now will set the value of the variable `ch` defined outside the loop instead of creating a new one with the same name.